# Routing table gateway

Tags: routing, gateway

I have a VPS (CentOS 5.6). Here is my routing table.

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination | Gateway | Genmask       | Flags | Metric | Ref | Use Iface
192.x.x.0   | 0.0.0.0 | 255.255.255.0 | U     | 0      | 0   | 0  venet0
169.x.0.0   | 0.0.0.0 | 255.255.0.0   | U     | 0      | 0   | 0  venet0
0.0.0.0     | 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0       | U     | 0      | 0   | 0  venet0
```

It works fine but I can't understand where is my gateway. Can somebody tell me how it works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a device-based default route, rather than an address-based default route.  That last line says to the kernel "if you want to get packets to anywhere else, just shove them out `venet0`.  That's a virtual ethernet interface, so I assume you're on a VPS of some kind - and the hosting server's OS will know how to get traffic to and from other physical hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't got one or haven't restarted networking since setting one;

Just edit /etc/sysconfig/network

> NETWORKING=yes
>
> HOSTNAME=whatever
>
> GATEWAY=whatever

Then restart networking using /etc/init.d/network restart